# Sci-fi movie released before 2011: scientist injects a pregnant woman with experimental stuff, the child grows very fast

Tags: story-identification, movie

At the time I watched the film, they broadcast foreign movies every Tuesday, including Chinese films, so I'm not sure if the language of the film is English​.

There are scenes at a lab. The main roles are a male scientist and another male scientist whose wife is also a scientist and got pregnant. They do experiments and inject something into the wife. The fetus grows very fast, so that the wife's belly explodes and it's a girl.

The main character raises her because the husband can't survive (can't remember what happens). The baby grows up super fast; she turns to a teenager and then a beautiful girl in a couple of days, and they fall in love, the girl getting old so that her hair is all white and she says her last words to him.

I remember (but am not sure) she has supernatural powers and does bad things.

The title in my language is 'Life in Number-of-days' (and the days are less than 10) because I wasn't at the TV when the title was displayed. I hoped it was *Splice* but it wasn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Life in a Day* (1999).

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0201732/):

> A scientific experiment in rapid-cell growth goes awry when a lab assistant steals the developed serum and injects it into his pregnant girl friend. The result is a child that grows through adulthood and will die within days, if a cure cannot be found.

More details from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Life_in_a_Day_(1999_film))...

> Peter finds the baby at his home/lab. Assisted by Charlotte "Charlie" Tanzi, he studies her as she grows from infancy to adulthood within two days, and names her Jasmine. [...]

> Meanwhile, Jasmine begins developing feelings for Peter, and sneaks away to explore the outside world. Peter returns to the lab, leaves Charlie with Mark's notes, and goes out to find Jasmine. He succeeds; Jasmine tells him she wanted to look pretty for him. [...]

> By the time Peter reaches the conservatory, Jasmine is elderly. They accept that it's too late to save her, and she dies in Peter's embrace.

---

Found with the Google query `scifi movie pregnant experiment girl grows fast`.

Comment: I just read the plot and Im searching for the film to watch, I will let you know if its the film. Thank you very much for helping me and thanks to you I will learn Google query! Wish you all the best

Comment: Seems I cant find the film to watch but I think its the film through the images. Thank you so very much